# How did the escape pods travel back through The Breach in Pacific Rim?

Tags: pacific-rim, kaiju, jaeger

[image]

Spoilerific.

> In the final moments of [Pacific Rim](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663662/), how were the Jaeger Pilots able to travel back through the Breach?

Earlier in the film, the scientific team coordinating the Jaeger program identify that the breach is protected by some kind of alien technology. It is said that the breach has a coded forcefield that will only grant access to a Kaiju, and this is given as explanation to why their previous ordinance had failed.

This knowledge is acted upon, and a Jaeger finally passes through the breach and into the unknown, catching a ride on a Kaiju. When the Jaeger initiates its self destruct sequence, the escape pods containing the pilots are ejected towards the surface, *back through the breach*.

> **How were the pods able to pass back through the forcefields if they were coded to only let Kaiju through, as stated earlier in the film?**

Comment: *"..that will only grant access to a Kaiju"*  Why lock the door on the inside as well?

Comment: One way lock - that was my assumption as well. What bothered me more was the apparent ability of the escape pod to outrun both the blast and the collapse of the breach.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Why not? I guess we don't know if its just as easy to make it one way, but if there are no circumstances when that anything but a Kaiju is needed to travel through, why bother to make it one way?

Comment: *"Why not?"*  Can easily be countered with *Why* *"I guess we don't know if its just as easy to make it one way, but if there are no circumstances.."*  ..and what if there are?  We could go backwards and forwards on this forever and not get any further.  It involves extra information not present (and heck, I haven't even *seen* the movie).

Comment: Ok, that answer makes sense if you've not seen it then. They just fire the Kaiju through to exterminate everything on the planet, the Kaiju aren't the commanding aliens they are the weapons deployed by them..Their Goal is indicated as simply to destroy life on the planet...that 'Extra information' is possibly present if you've seen the film, sorry.

Comment: After seeing the movie I'm of the same opinion.  The bigger question is as hinted by Sebastian_H - why there was any facility for a Kaiju to return.

Comment: I would think it wasn't meant for Kaiju to return, but the Precursors themselves. They probably ride Kaiju or Kaiju-like creatures/ships, and they obviously want to go through this portal eventually. When they do go through as scouts or colonizers, they will probably at first want the ability to return.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible and not even unlikely that the protection mechanism was designed to work only one way. The idea behind it was apparently to stop the invaded world from sending something back to the invaders world like WMDs or troops.

There is no need to implement the same protection on their side. I think you can compare it to a basic firewall setup. You usually allow all outgoing connections, assuming that they are harmless but you would block all incoming connections except those you want to allow.

Although I wonder why the Kaiju needed a way back in the first place, as they were nothing more then disposable weapons.

Comment: I think your answer is very good at explaining a very likely scenario, but I'd be interested in seeing if anyone knows for sure...? As you've said yourself, the Kaiju were just disposable ordnance, which is interesting in considering why the aliens would even bother creating a one-way system.

Answer (score -1):

It’s like what Hermann said. He said it was like a supermarket, where they scan the code, then if it’s correct, they let you pass. If you go into the supermarket, they don’t need to check you. Same with the breach. They don’t need to check if it’s a kaiju or not, because it’s only supposed gto let kaiju in. That didn’t work out very well, though, or else the kaiju threat would still be going on.

Comment: This answer simply restates the answer above without adding anything useful.